# How to flip a stacked barplot() in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a stacked barplot that looks like this [image: vertical stacked barplot]

I want to flip this barplot so that it looks like this: [image: horizontal stacked barplot]

I've tried setting `horiz=FALSE` to TRUE but it just gives me 
[image]

My code is:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  row.names =c(100),
  Male =c(50),
  Female =c(50))

x <- barplot(t(as.matrix(mydata)), horiz=TRUE, axes=FALSE, col=c("yellow", "green"), 
             legend=TRUE, border=NA, xlim=c(0,8), args.legend=
               list(bty="n", border=NA), 
             ylab="Cumulative percentage", xlab="Village number")
text(x, mydata$Male-10, labels=round(mydata$Male), col="black")
text(x, mydata$Male+10, labels=100-round(mydata$Male))
```

Comment: It's because you have `xlim=c(0,8)`. If the chart is horizontal the percentage is on the x-axis, so it needs to go to 100. This also means your axis  labels are flipped.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, Create an answer and I will accept